# Sort multidimensional NumPy array by norm over a dimension

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am working with a multidimensional NumPy array `a` which is a "vector" of say `2x2` matrices.
I want to sort `a` such that the `2x2` matrices are sorted by their row-norms.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[3, 4],
               [1, 2]],

              [[5, 6],
               [7, 8]]])    
sortidxs = np.argsort(np.linalg.norm(a, axis=-1))
a = np.array([a[_][sortidxs[_]] for _ in range(a.shape[0])])

# And the final output should be:

print(a)
[[[1 2]
  [3 4]]

  [[5 6]
  [7 8]]]
```

The above code snippet does what I am looking for (not quite, look at the Edit below). But I was looking for a way to avoid the loop

```
a = np.array([a[_][sortidxs[_]] for _ in range(a.shape[0])])
```

**-- Edit --**

The example above missed a crucial part of the of the question.`a` could have more "empty" dimensions i.e.

```
a = np.array([[[3, 4],
               [1, 2]],

              [[5, 6],
               [7, 8]]])
a = a.reshape((2,1,2,2))
```

`a` now looks like:

```
In [257]: a
Out[257]: 
array([[[[3, 4],
         [1, 2]]],

       [[[5, 6],
         [7, 8]]]])
```

and after sorting it should be

```
In [259]: a
Out[259]: 
array([[[[1, 2],
         [3, 4]]],

       [[[5, 6],
         [7, 8]]]])
```

`a` could also have the following dimension `(1,2,2,2)` or more such "empty" dimensions in the beginning. I would want the sort to work in these cases too.

Comment: So you only want to sort the norm along the `axis = 1`, what if you have `[[[1,2], [5,6]], [[3,4], [7,8]]]`?

Comment: @Psidom can you elaborate further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None], sortidxs]
```

Sample run -

```
In [144]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,3,4))

In [145]: a
Out[145]: 
array([[[1, 1, 5, 5],
        [1, 1, 7, 5],
        [6, 1, 2, 8]],

       [[7, 2, 5, 4],
        [3, 7, 3, 7],
        [8, 4, 4, 6]]])

In [146]: sortidxs = np.argsort(np.linalg.norm(a, axis=-1))

In [147]: np.array([a[_][sortidxs[_]] for _ in range(a.shape[0])])
Out[147]: 
array([[[1, 1, 5, 5],
        [1, 1, 7, 5],
        [6, 1, 2, 8]],

       [[7, 2, 5, 4],
        [3, 7, 3, 7],
        [8, 4, 4, 6]]])

In [149]: a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None], sortidxs]
Out[149]: 
array([[[1, 1, 5, 5],
        [1, 1, 7, 5],
        [6, 1, 2, 8]],

       [[7, 2, 5, 4],
        [3, 7, 3, 7],
        [8, 4, 4, 6]]])
```

**Further performance boost**

We can optimize on computing `sortidxs` with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
sortidxs = np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',a,a).argsort()
```

Let's time it and verify this idea -

```
In [94]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(20,30,40))

In [95]: %timeit np.argsort(np.linalg.norm(a, axis=-1))
10000 loops, best of 3: 63.5 µs per loop

In [96]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',a,a).argsort()
10000 loops, best of 3: 19.7 µs per loop

In [97]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(200,300,400))

In [98]: %timeit np.argsort(np.linalg.norm(a, axis=-1))
10 loops, best of 3: 88.6 ms per loop

In [99]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij',a,a).argsort()
10 loops, best of 3: 22.6 ms per loop
```

---

**Array with higher dimensions**

For the additional case of `a` being a `4D` array, we need to use more arrays for indexing.

1] For first axis : Use `np.arange(a.shape[0])` with two new axes at the end.

2] For second axis : Use `np.arange(a.shape[0])` with one new axis at the end.

3] For third axis : Use `sortidxs` for indexing into this.

Thus, we would have :

```
m,n,r,s = a.shape
out = a[np.arange(m)[:,None,None],np.arange(n)[:,None], sortidxs]
```

**Arrays with singleton dim (dim with length=1)**

As a special case, let's say the second axis of the input array is already a singleton one, we could simply use `0` for that axis and thus simplify things, like so -

```
a[np.arange(m)[:,None,None],0, sortidxs]
```

Sample run -

```
In [58]: a = np.array([[[3, 4],
    ...:                [1, 2]],
    ...: 
    ...:               [[5, 6],
    ...:                [7, 8]]])
    ...: 
    ...: a = a.reshape((2,1,2,2))
    ...: 

In [59]: sortidxs = np.argsort(np.linalg.norm(a, axis=-1))

In [60]: a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None,None],0, sortidxs]
Out[60]: 
array([[[[1, 2],
         [3, 4]]],


       [[[5, 6],
         [7, 8]]]])
```

Another sample run for an array with a generic shape of `(2,3,4)` to make things very clear -

```
In [70]: a = np.random.randint(0,9,(2,1,3,4))

In [71]: a
Out[71]: 
array([[[[6, 4, 8, 6],
         [4, 0, 1, 0],
         [5, 3, 2, 5]]],


       [[[3, 6, 0, 4],
         [6, 2, 5, 2],
         [0, 8, 0, 8]]]])

In [72]: sortidxs = np.argsort(np.linalg.norm(a, axis=-1))

In [73]: sortidxs
Out[73]: 
array([[[1, 2, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 2]]])

In [74]: a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None,None],0, sortidxs]
Out[74]: 
array([[[[4, 0, 1, 0],
         [5, 3, 2, 5],
         [6, 4, 8, 6]]],


       [[[3, 6, 0, 4],
         [6, 2, 5, 2],
         [0, 8, 0, 8]]]])
```

Comment: I edited my question with some more details (forgot to mention it the first time around) can you update your answer ?

Comment: @KayGee Added in the latest edit at the end of the post.

Answer (score 1):

Since `sortidxs` is contain the desire indices for each axis (from start to end) you can generate the first axis range by `np.arange(a.shape[0])` and pass it as the first axis while indexing:

```
In [31]: x,y, z = a.shape
In [32]: i, j = sortidxs.shape
In [33]: a[np.repeat(np.arange(x)[:, none], i, 1),sortidxs]

Out[33]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])
```

As a more simplified way, **in this case** (as you mentioned in comment) you can just pass the `np.arange(x)[:, None]` without using `repeat()` function but if you want the variant number of items along the 2nd and 3rd indices or etc for other dimensional arrays `repeat` will give you the correct answer. Also note that in those case you can also pass the respective indices along each axis separately.

```
In [107]: a[np.arange(x)[:, None],sortidxs]
Out[107]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])
```

Comment: Note that your output is not the same as the expected output.

Comment: @KayGee Yep, I forgot its a 3D array.

Comment: I believe you don't need the `np.repeat`  i.e. `a[np.arange(x).reshape(y,1),sortidxs]` should work. Thanks !

Comment: @Divakar That's correct or we can just use broadcasting (`In [107]: a[np.arange(x)[:, None],sortidxs]
Out[107]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])
`), but I doubt if it words for multiple shapes and when we want variant number of items.

Comment: I edited my question with some more details (forgot to mention it the first time around) can you update your answer ?

Comment: @KayGee Divakar added the general approach, you can use that one.